# Protege OWL DataProperty on ObjectProperty

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I am trying to express this one:

> Manchester distance from London is 335 km.

I have created class city and now I am thinking to create and objectProperty hasDistance with Domain City and Range City.

But where can I declare the real distance for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is in actual fact an example of an [n-ary relation](https://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/). In such a case the relation is modelled as a class rather than a property. For this purpose, let us assume we introduce a class `DistanceBetweenTwoCities`. Hence, one way to model this is as follows:

```
Class: City
Class: DistanceBetweenTwoCities

ObjectProperty: hasCity1
    Domain: DistanceBetweenTwoCities    
    Range: City

ObjectProperty: hasCity2
    Domain: DistanceBetweenTwoCities
    Range: City

DataProperty: hasDistance
    Domain: DistanceBetweenTwoCities
    Range: xsd:integer
```

To now state the distance between London and Manchester:

```
Individual: distanceLondonToManchester
    Types: 
    DistanceBetweenTwoCities

    Facts:  
     hasCity1  london,
     hasCity2  manchester,
     hasDistance  335


Individual: london
    Types: City

Individual: manchester
    Types: City
```

Note: Strictly speaking it is not necessary to introduce two different properties `hasCity1` and `hasCity2`. We could have used only `hasCity`. I only introduced 2 properties to make the n-ary relation a bit more obvious.

**Update 20190320**

If you have another distance you have to present you can add another individual of type `DistanceBetweenTwoCities`:

```
Individual: distanceLondonToAthens
    Types: 
    DistanceBetweenTwoCities

    Facts:  
      hasCity1  london,
      hasCity2  athens,
      hasDistance  3000


Individual: athens
     Types: City
```

Comment: I understand your point and I am trying to follow it but what happens when I have two distances. 1)Athens to London:3000km and 2) Athens to Korinthos:82km How to distinguish what is the valid? see [https://imgur.com/a/QsqDPmy]

Comment: Each distance between 2 cities will require a new individual of type `DistanceBetweenTwoCities`. I will update the answer to illustrate this.

Comment: What do you mean by valid?

Comment: it is not practical to create for every pair of cities a new DistanceBetweenTwoCities, and I think it is against the point of semantic.

Comment: There is simply no way your ontology will know the distance between two cities if you do not supply the information.

Comment: @giorgionasis what means against semantic? Semantic of what? And just to recap, OWL just provides binary relations, and n-aray relations have to modeled like shown in the answer here. and alternative might be reification which is verbose in RDF. if that's not what you want, a property graph model instead of OWL/RDF is maybe more appropriate